# Deleting particular named directories from parent and all child folders

Tags: linux, command-line, command

My folder hierarchy is like A/B/C/D.

So now each folder contains directory named CVS.

My purpose is I want to delete all CVS named directories from all folders.

I frequently tried to execute from parent folder(A Folder) `rm -rf "CVS"` , but it deletes CVS folder only from A folder and it's not fulfilling my needs.

I want to delete total 1200 folders named CVS.

If you can let me know appropriate command to delete CVS named directory recursively from parent to all sub folder it would be great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the find command.

```
find pathname -type d -iname "CVS" -delete
```

In path name , You can give the path from which directory you have to delete.

Or else try this.

```
 find pathname -type d -iname "CVS" -exec rm -rf \{\} \;
```

Comment: If i give pathname as my current directory(which is parent directory) it throws an error like find: invalid predicate `-delete' ..

Comment: @user3706789 If you are executing from the current directory that time you don't need to give the path name. Find is take current directory as default.

Comment: Seems something wrong with above command..
If I enter above command it enters into another prompt like:
>
Like it enters for GDB..